# What kind of philospher believes many philospical issues can be reduced to defining words?

Tags: reference-request, metaphilosophy

I will take Fatalism vs Compatibilism as an example. I hold that the only difference between them is the definition of free will. Namely, I prefer the Compatibilistic definition, that free will is acting according to one's motivations (essentially), and therefore I am a Compatibilistic person. I also believe though that fatalism is not necessarily false, and that it simply uses a different definition for free will (a sentient being having undetermined future behaviour.) I just think the Compatibilistic definition is preferable to the fatalist one. The only issues that remain are scientific and/or theological ones (does quantum mechanics discount fatalism entirely?/does God's omniscience allow free will to exist in accordance with a fatalists definition of free will?)
 Other examples would include defining precisely good and evil before doing ethnics and defining existence before talking about whether something exists,

What is it called to approach philosophical issues like this, reducing them to a preference of definitions, and maybe with some scientific and/or religious loose ends. More over, is there a name for what it is called if one believes that all philosophical issues can be solved in this manner?

Note: An emphasis is put on how trivial a philosophical issue can be made with precise definitions.

Note: This is contrasted the using solely a bunch of philosophical thought experiments and using vague philosophical language. It is also contrasted too using vague philosophical definitions.

Comment: Since *language is the medium of philosophy*, all philosophy is based on words and their meaning.  You can pretend whatever you like, but there are no other options.  I.e., there is not a name for philosophy "which is based on defining words" in relation to something else because **all philosophy is based on defining words**.

Comment: Put another way: You've explained what you mean by "this approach", but you do not contrast it with some other approach.  So a counter question: **What kind of philosopher believes there are issues that *cannot* be "reduced to defining words"?**.

Comment: +goldilocks It seems though that in a lot of discussions of philosophy words just go undefined.

Comment: Yes, people are slippery that way ;|

Comment: The Stanford entry for [free will](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/free-will-foreknowledge/) contains no definition of it.

Comment: I would say this is a first step towards analytic philosophy.

Comment: @PavelC ROTFL.  PyRulez, The SEP is not a perfect reference, of course.  It's normal for philosophers to not provide a dictionary definition of the terms they use since philosophy is often about exploring a concept (literally or rhetorically) -- you can't really set out to explore something if you've already seen it all clearly to start with.

Comment: @goldilocks If you give me a source that actually defines the words it talks about before using them, it would be a great help.

Comment: There is such a thing as a "Dictionary of Philosophy", which does exactly that (I don't have any online ones to recommend, but if you search that phrase you'll find some, and there are others have long been available in print).  The problem is they need to provide multiple definitions for multiple philosophers, since they don't all use the same word the same way.  Further, people will write entire volumes that come down to defining a small set of words, but a dictionary doesn't have the space (nor their readers the time).  However, they can provide a decent starting point.

Comment: Note that wikipedia is a bit more all encompassing than SEP presumably because it has much more people-hours behind it.  So if you don't find something satisfactory in SEP, check wikipedia.

Comment: +goldilocks Wikipedia doesn't do what you say either. All of the online sources i have seen for free will just go on philosophizing and not really doing any defining unless it is a vague definition that can be interpreted different ways.

Comment: +goldilocks I put what it's contrasted too.

Comment: **If you've got an answer to the question, it goes in an answer.** Please take extended discussion to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/538/the-symposium)

Comment: "semanticist" is probably too short to be a valid answer

Comment: @goldilocks This is simply an opinion you are presenting as fact --or to be more precise, it is the position of a school of philosophy, not the position of all philosophers.

Comment: @ChrisSunami No, in that sense there are exactly ZERO positions which belong to all philosophers -- I'd argue for *cogito ergo sum* but I would lose that too.  I don't object to the idea that there aren't corner cases which come down to "can't be defined in words" but I'd also say those are the points where philosophy out of pure self respect should bow out of whatever it is being discussed.  As I wrote the first time, *contrast it with some other approach*.

Comment: @goldilocks Every philosopher uses words, but not every philosopher takes defining words as the central activity of philosophy.  For Plato, for instance, the goal of philosophy was to illuminate deeper Truth, words were simply a (flawed) vehicle to advance that goal.  On a separate note: If you're determined to continue promoting this point of view, offer it as an answer, and let the community agree or disagree.

Answer (score 6):

The philosopher who most famously argued that the majority of philosophical problems reduce to confusion over definitions is [Wittgenstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophical_Investigations).  The philosophic movement most closely associated with Wittgenstein is *analytic philosophy*, although being an analytic philosopher does not entail that one agrees with that premise.

There's not necessarily a term in general usage specifically referring to endorsement of that point of view (although I have heard the coinage *syntheism* used for the particular application of that principle to the subject of religion).

Answer (score 3):

If your question is to mean "what sort of philosopher believes definitions are important?"

Then my answer would be any good philosopher believes that (good here being about skill -- not morality).

---

But your question is "What kind of philosopher believes many philosophical issues can be reduced to defining words?"

I take this to mean that if we get our definitions straight, then the problems and disagreements disappear.

On this definition, I might say a dogmatic philosopher.

But your examples seem confused as to what the domain of science is versus philosophy or theology. The question of what a scientific discovery means -- like QM and Heisenberg uncertainty, that seems to be clearly philosophical question rather than purely scientific one. Science can show what is happening in the physical world. The interpretative challenge is philosophy.

If there's a group that thought everything could be solved just by getting the meaning of our sentences right, then that would have been early 20th century analytic philosophy through to the logical positivists and *early* philosophy of language. I take what they sought to be somewhat similar to what you're wanting in terms of approach.

---

On the other hand, I think many contemporary analytic philosophers and philosophers of language don't think that project works... so I would not call it simply "analytic philosophy."

Answer (score 1):

You asked the question: "What kind of philosopher believes many philosophical issues can be reduced to defining words?"  I like this question.  Also, one respondent asked: "What sort of philosopher believes definitions are important?"  I also like his question as part of his response.  The answer, of course, without seeming trite, is--"a defining philosopher."  I remember reading on 'defining philosophy' in F.A. Schaeffer's book on epistemology, *He is There and He is not Silent* (1972).  Schaeffer dubs Wittgenstein a "...defining philosopher."  This particular twist in philosophy is related to 'language philosophy', to 'structuralism', and to 'logical positivism' or extreme rationalism (radical empiricism).  Today, all of this is simply referred to as "analytic philosophy," as one respondent shared.  Schaeffer has many good remarks regarding 'logical positivism', including comments in his book--*The God Who Is There* (1968)--on the logical positivist speaker who attempted to conduct a seminar at La Abri (Switzerland) by beginning his talk, "When this data gets to you."  Of course, Schaeffer had to temporarily stop the seminar and point out: "In the philosophy of logical positivism there is no such thing as 'data'."  Or, "What is 'data' in 'defining philosophy'?"  Or, "What 'data' is reliable?"  Or, "Whose data is this?"  The seminar, of course, moved from a temporary stop to a heated end, as the participants could not agree on a 'definition' for the single word 'data'.  You see, some philosophical treatments are wholly without a 'numerator'.  These treatments are 'exclusively' related to the self-contained 'denominator' (left brain), with no recognition of that which is 'above'.  This was my point in my question regarding *neurophysiology* (see on).  However, as another respondent questioned: "What kind of philosopher believes there are issues that cannot be 'reduced to defining words'"?  I would suggest, but not at all flippantly, "...a metaphysician."  Hegel always struck me as this type of philosopher... "...Oh so upper story, he is."  That is to say, Hegel is almost 'religious' in his "cyphering".  Compared to other thinkers, Hegel is sometimes *all* numerator (right brain) and no denominator.  Most "exclusively" *spiritual* responses are much the same.